# Out of memory when DataFrame.resample() is called in pandas on small dataset

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` that has a number of string columns and a datetime column.  I want to resample the datetime columns appropriately using pandas `df.resample()`. For instance, my data looks like:

```
from pandas import *
import numpy as np

df = DataFrame({
'username' : ["bob","bob","nancy"],
'session' : ["one","two","three"],
'timestamp' : [np.datetime64("2012-12-12 17:53:36"),np.datetime64("2012-12-13 17:53:36"),np.datetime64("2012-12-14 17:53:36")] })
```

I add a new column for counting:

```
df["cnt"]=1
```

Then I try and resample the `DataFrame` to daily using `df.resample("1D", how="sum")`.  This doesn't work:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-01a264cf511c> in <module>()
----> 1 df.resample("1D", how="sum")

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.pyc in resample(self, rule, how, axis, fill_method, closed, label, convention, kind, loffset, limit, base)
    288                               fill_method=fill_method, convention=convention,
    289                               limit=limit, base=base)
--> 290         return sampler.resample(self)
    291 
    292     def first(self, offset):

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.pyc in resample(self, obj)
     98             return obj
     99         else:  # pragma: no cover
--> 100             raise TypeError('Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex')
    101 
    102         rs_axis = rs._get_axis(self.axis)

TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex or PeriodIndex
```

If I promote the timestamp to an index, that doesn't seem to help, presumably because `sum()` has troubles running on my other values.  I tried creating a multiindex and then unstacking a few times:

```
df.set_index(["timestamp","username","session"], inplace=True)
df.unstack().unstack().resample("1D",how="min")
```

This works perfectly in the tiny example here.  In my application code it doesn't, and we get an out of memory error.  Here is an example that uses the sizes of data (both in number of elements and in form, since they are mostly md5 hashes).  This dies very quickly on a machine with lots of memory, so maybe it is a bug?

```
import random
import md5
def gethash(i):
    return md5.new(str(random.random())).hexdigest()

def gettimestamp(i):
    return np.datetime64("2012-" + str(random.randint(10,12)) + "-" + str(random.randint(10,28)) + " 17:53:36")

df = DataFrame({
'username' : map(gethash,xrange(10000)),
'session' : map(gethash,xrange(10000)),
'timestamp' : map(gettimestamp,xrange(10000))
})

df["cnt"]=1

df.set_index(["timestamp","username","session"], inplace=True)
df.unstack().unstack().resample("1D",how="min")
```

The only work around we have found is to instead we truncate the dates using numpy datatypes.  E.g.

```
df['timestamp']=df.timestamp.values.astype('datetime64[D]')
```

This limits us to whatever options the `astype()` cast allows.  For instance how can we do resampling to every two days?  In pandas, it would be:

```
df.resample("2D",how="min")
```

(which works with the toy example, but not in our full code, because of the memory issue)

Is there another way to get the same effect of `resample()` using largish datasets in pandas?

Comment: Which version of pandas are you using?

Comment: Can you clearly explain what exact 'effect' you want to obtain? Because in your example all `username` and `session` values are unique? Is doing a groupby on `username` and `session` and resampling on those groups a possible direction?

Comment: @joris I'm using version 0.12.0

Comment: @joris The effect I'm looking for is to have timestamps rounded/truncated into arbitrary groupings. So being able to truncate them to one day, two days, etc.  I would prefer to use the pandas format for this versus the numpy datatype mentioned.  My example is unfortunate, but I couldn't share my dataset - in my raw dataset, sessions and users have lots of duplicate (web logs, one use with many sessions, many timestamps within a session).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like this. Here's the explanation.

Set a timestamp index, sort the timestamp index (the way I am doing it here, you don't need to sort, while a resample *does* need it sorted). and perform the resample in whatever frequency you want (1D in this example); this is tantamount to a resample but it just 'groups' and doesn't do the calculation (yet).

then in the apply, do your calculation, which in this case is another groupby.

```
In [74]: df.set_index('timestamp').sort_index().groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('1D')).apply(lambda x: x.groupby(['username','session']).sum())
Out[74]: 
                             cnt
           username session     
2012-12-12 bob      one        1
2012-12-13 bob      two        1
2012-12-14 nancy    three      1

[3 rows x 1 columns]
```

This is not possible ATM to do all at once (its an outstanding request here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3794

Your example is too simple to return anything interesting (and your bigger example is too random, not enough grouping).

This should not be a memory problem. You almost never want to unstack twice in a row on a large set as its memory conducive.

Comment: This seems to do it, thanks!  I can't say I understand why the other method wouldn't work, is there something conceptually wrong? Should I file a bug?  Pivottable() also throws a memory error.

Comment: And just to clarify, this is first grouping everything by time, then sub grouping based on hashed_username.  So if I had more string columns, I would need to continue nesting groupby functions until I was left with just numeric values?

Comment: no, you don't need to nest anymore; it's a bug right now that you cannot group by time AND by one or more string fields

Comment: the method u suggested (multiple unstacking) works but will blow up memory because it's not meant to be used like this